# How to add subview to AVPlayer in Airplay Mode?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer, avplayeritem

I have added subview to `AVPlayer` successfully. But, when I am playing it in the airplay mode, its not appearing in the Apple TV. Can anyone help me on this?

How to add subview to `AVPlayer` in Airplay Mode?

Comment: Are you reading this article ? http://prog3.com/sbdm/blog/kmyhy/article/details/9064167

Comment: Is that the Data for Avplayer is from Live URL or From Local???

Comment: @Muruganandam.S The Data for Avplayer is from Live URL

Comment: hello @Anand, did you find a solution?